# How to use Apple's Screen Time API in React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I would like to add a feature to my React Native project that controls the apps available to the user while my app is open.

I think I can do this using Apple's Screen Time API, but I couldn't find any reference on how to use this API with React Native.

Here is a link that explains what can be done with the Screen Time API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/screentime

You can also see some features that I can use in Xcode in the photos I will attach.

I would appreciate if you can help me with this.

[Xcode capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHFSl.png)
[Seems like this on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jZnS.png)

I would like to add a feature to my React Native project that controls the apps available to the user while my app is open with Screen Time API.

Comment: You will need to find or write a plug-in to expose the screen time APIs to react native. Asking for recommendations for such a plug in would be off topic.